# Why brew install shivammathur/php/php@8.2 has got dependencies that has nothing to do with php (ninja, llvm, rust, ruby, vim) on MacOS Catalina

Tags: php, homebrew, macos-catalina, php-8.2

Can't achieve `brew install shivammathur/php/php@8.2`  on MacOS Catalina as the dependencies take many hours to build. As the warning states, there is not more support on Catalina but I just don't understand why should I build llvm, ruby, rust or vim to install PHP.

For instance llvm took 233 minutes
 [/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1: 7,207 files, 1.5GB, built in 233 minutes 27 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com)

Here is the full list of dependencies and the command line taped

```
$ brew install shivammathur/php/php@8.2
Warning: You are using macOS 10.15.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
It is expected behaviour that some formulae will fail to build in this old version.
It is expected behaviour that Homebrew will be buggy and slow.
Do not create any issues about this on Homebrew's GitHub repositories.
Do not create any issues even if you think this message is unrelated.
Any opened issues will be immediately closed without response.
Do not ask for help from Homebrew or its maintainers on social media.
You may ask for help in Homebrew's discussions but are unlikely to receive a response.
Try to figure out the problem yourself and submit a fix as a pull request.
We will review it but may or may not accept it.
[
.....
]
==> Installing php@8.2 from shivammathur/php
==> Installing dependencies for shivammathur/php/php@8.2: ninja, meson, libsodium, lua, ncurses, berkeley-db@5, gdbm, perl, libyaml, libgit2, z3, swig, llvm, rust, ruby, vim, libvmaf, yasm, aom, libavif, gd, krb5, libpq, libzip, oniguruma and tidy-html5
```

I hope not to have to build non-related dependencies to install PHP on MacOS Catalinan and achieve the installation in minutes and not hours

Comment: You can ask to the upstream, https://github.com/shivammathur/homebrew-php